# Running cypress tests on chart.js bar chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, cypress

I'm using cypress.io to test my react web app. The app contains some chart.js charts. I'm able to identify the bar chart after setting an id.

```
<Bar id="goodBadBar" options={optionsBar} data={barData}/>
```

Now I want to verify that the chart has two bars. How do I "find" that there are two bars?

This is my current code:

```
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/totals");
    // The chart should be visible
    cy.get("#goodBadBar").should("be.visible").should("have.length", 2);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't select it with cypress, since it is drawn on the canvas and does not contain dom elements what cypress looks for. So you need to use an image based test for this. It can be done with the [snapshot plugin](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/01/16/end-to-end-snapshot-testing/) or any other image based framework.

Although you should not need to test third party libraries. The testing that it shows as it needs to show is done in the lib itself so as long as you supply the correct config it will render correctly

Comment: Thank you for the info. I noticed that it only shows a canvas, but thought it would be good to test the number of bars. Since you are saying the lib does the testing already, I will only test that it "shows" on the page.